# Wallpaper goes crazy after login Xubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, xubuntu, login, desktop-background, xfdesktop

After upgrading from Xubuntu 14.10 to Xubuntu 15.04, I have ahd a major wallpaper issue. After every login it becomes weird. It has some little lines and a big black lane at the center-right of the screen, like this:
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkm8C.png). After changing the wallpaper this problem gets fixed for that session. Could you please help me?

Comment: Nothing? No one?